# PHP: substr returns empty string

Tags: php, string, substr

The substr function in my PHP file has an empty string as a result.

Here is my PHP code:

```
    <?php
$requestArray = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"User-agent: MKUxA&8PtUYP(d3So)pfPSIvD5cf75"
  )
);

$stream = stream_context_create($requestArray);
$streamResult = file_get_contents('https://beoordelingen.feedbackcompany.nl/samenvoordeel/scripts/flexreview/getreviewxml.cfm?ws=9673&publishIDs=0&nor=0&publishDetails=0&publishDetailScores=0&publishOnHold=0&sort=desc&foreign=1&v=3&publishDetailScores=1&Basescore=10', false, $stream);

$str = substr($streamResult, 0, 3);
var_dump($str);

echo "<br>";
var_dump($streamResult);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($http_response_header);

?>
```

This is the result:

```
string(3) "string(251) " 8.7109https://beoordelingen.feedbackcompany.nl/NL-NL/De%2DMariannehoeve.html "
array(6) { [0]=> string(15) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" [1]=> string(37) "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8" [2]=> string(25) "Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5" [3]=> string(21) "X-Powered-By: ASP.NET" [4]=> string(35) "Date: Mon, 22 Feb 2016 13:39:34 GMT" [5]=> string(17) "Connection: close" }
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and help me out?

Comment: What's the result of `var_dump($streamResult);`? The result you inputted?

Comment: It's everything in the result but: string(3)

Comment: Are you successfully getting the `streamResult`?

Comment: Perhaps you have to check your system or browser cache; this is the output of var_dump($str); on my local environment: string '<?x' (length=3)

Comment: show `var_dump($http_response_header);`

Comment: edited the post, added a var_dump of $http_response_header. Also deleted my cache

Answer (score 0):

The content is correctly returned, but you see above result in browser because the browser interpret the tags.

Your result is:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
>     <rating><score>8.7</score><scoremax>10</scoremax><noReviews>9</noReviews><detailslink>https://beoordelingen.feedbackcompany.nl/NL-NL/De%2DMariannehoeve.html</detailslink><reviewDetails></reviewDetails></rating>
> ```

So, `substr($streamResult, 0, 3)` is `<?x`, that — rendered — is:

> 

Also, `$streamResult` is above XML that — rendered — is:

> 8.7109https://beoordelingen.feedbackcompany.nl/NL-NL/De%2DMariannehoeve.html

If you want see the result in the browser, write this:

```
 echo htmlentities( $streamResult );
```

#### Edit:

The returned data is XML, so — to parse it — you have to use `DOMDocument` (or another parser):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML( $streamResult );
$score = $dom->getElementsbyTagName( 'score' )->item(0)->nodeValue;

echo $score;
```

The example abowe will output:

> 8.7

Comment: Okay, so when I want the characters between the <score> and </score> i have to do a substring till <score> ?