# Why does substr() return an empty string?

Tags: r, substr

I don't know if I have a logical error, but my `substr()` function is keep returning an empty string? My initial thought was that I am cutting the string wrong, however even with a lower starting value, I am getting null string in my dataframe column.

I have looked at this PHP question to get some information, but didn't work: [PHP: substr returns empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554695/php-substr-returns-empty-string)

Reproducible example-

```r
#Original Data set str() output
#'data.frame':  9245 obs. of  3 variables:
#$ Latitude   : num  29.7 29.7 29.7 29.6 29.7 ...
#$ Longitude  : num  -82.3 -82.4 -82.3 -82.4 -82.3 ...
#$ Census Code: chr  "120010011003032" "120010010004035" "120010002003009" "120010015213000" ...

#For example, even if I do this:
base::substr("120010011003032", 6, 1)

#Output : ""
#Desired output: 001100
```

I needed to cut census codes to generate tract information, and the tract information is usually first two being the state, next three the county, and the following six the tract.

Comment: The answers have fixed the R side of things, but for comparison: PHP's [`substr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) arguments are `string`, `start`, and `length`. Excel's [`MID`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mid-midb-functions-d5f9e25c-d7d6-472e-b568-4ecb12433028) function arguments are `text`, `start_num`, and `num_chars`. Both of those work on the *length* of the substring. In contrast, python uses `string[start:end]` semantics, similar to R's arguments of `substr(x, start, stop)`. So the methods are either start:len or start:stop, R chooses the latter.

Comment: Thank you for a good information, appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
base::substr("120010011003032", 6, 11)

"001100"
```

Comment: Wow, I seriously didn't notice that. I thought it was 11. I don't know. I think I need a break. Thank you Eugene.

Answer (score 2):

You need `base::substr("120010011003032", 1, 6)` ! (EDIT: or `11, 6` per your comment)

The arguments are `start, stop` not `length, start`; see [the doc](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/substr.html) or type `?base::substr`. Tip: always triple-check the R doc first. And also try copy-pasting the working examples it gives you, then see if/how they differ from yours. Or just try various argument values.

Comment: Sorry, I thought my end was 11, I just spotted it now with the help of Eugene.

Comment: No wiorries! Alwasy triple-check the doc, and copy-paste the working examples it gives. Often with R doc, it's easier to visually diff a good command-line from a bad one, than plough through the doc. Or experiment with different arg values.

Comment: Understood, I don't have any excuse. I was keep checking with same string with different start. I should have done better.

Comment: Hey it's cool! We all did similar in our time. I'm just passing on my wisdom...

Comment: Thank you smci, appreciate you helping out new R users like me!